# User home shortcut for Launch4J

Tags: java, xml, type-conversion, exe, launch4j

I would like to use a shortcut for the users home directory to use in the Launch4J xml.

I know I could just use an environment variable to specify my user home specifically. However, what I want is something like ${user.home} in ant build files that can be used for multiple users.

This is because the locations of the files we use are the same relative to our home directories.

I already know that we could use environment variables relative to our individual locations if one person decides to put files in different locations, but this happens to work out easier for us.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @CamHart Unfortunately, I have not yet gotten a response for this. I am probably going to look into using other software than Launch4J in the future.